# Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysqli, bindparam

The bind parameter function, `bind_param()` is considered a non object and keeps throwing errors that hurt my head as i'm new to the PHP thing. The code used to connect to the database was originally throwing errors, even though I copied it from my login script where it was working...

```
<?php
class User {
    private $result;
    private static $db;

    public function __construct($cookie) {
        self::$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', '', 'dbname');
        var_dump(self::$db);
        
        $query = self::$db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE cookie=?');
        var_dump($query);
        $query->bind_param('s', $cookie);
        

        $this->result = $query->get_result()->fetch_array();
    }
    
    public static function checkUser($cookie) {
        self::$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', "", 'dbname');
        
        $query = self::$db->prepare('SELECT cookie FROM users WHERE cookie=?');
        $query->bind_param('s', $cookie);

        $result = $query->get_result()->fetch_array();
        
        if ($cookie == $result[0]) return true;

        return false;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->result['name'];
    }

    public function getSurname() {
        return $this->result['surname'];
    }

    public function getEmail() {
        return $this->result['email'];
    }

    public function getGroup() {
        return $this->result['perm_group'];
    }

    public function getEstablishment() {
        return $this->result['establishment'];
    }
}
?>
```

The idea was to to make a class (User) so that we can call functions from other pages to get details of the users, such as Cookie. I've been doing this for hours and I honestly don't know whats going on.

Comment: what does `var_dump(self::$db);` giving?

Comment: probably connection problems

Comment: object(mysqli)[2]
  public 'affected_rows' => int 0
  public 'client_info' => string 'mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: bf9ad53b11c9a57efdb1057292d73b928b8c5c77 $' (length=79)
  public 'client_version' => int 50011
  public 'connect_errno' => int 0
  public 'connect_error' => null
  public 'errno' => int 0
  public 'error' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'error_list' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'field_count' => int 0
  public 'host_info' => string 'Localhost via UNIX socket' (length=25)
  public 'info' => null
  public 'insert_id' => int 0

Comment: No connection problems, we connect successfully

Comment: in your checkUser function, why are you establishing connection again? Doesn't the `self:db` have the connection from `construct`?

Comment: I'm not calling the constructor, so the self:db would be empty/undefined otherwise.

Comment: You don't call contrusctor. That is the first function to be called in a class. It calls itself.

Comment: Won't it only call itself if creating a new User, which we don't do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysqli\_fetch\_assoc() expects parameter / Call to a member function bind\_param() errors. How to get the actual mysql error and fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[mysqli::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) returns false, if an error occurred.

```
$query = self::$db->prepare('SELECT cookie FROM users WHERE cookie=?');
$query->bind_param('s', $cookie);
```

If there is an error, you have no result-object to call bind_param on.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was real simple, we forgot to have a column to store cookies.

Sorry for the stupid question ladies